# The OpenSSH upgraded to version of today automatically

Tags: macos, ssh

I issue the following command follwing a command line instruction book,

```
$ ssh remote-sys
ssh: Could not resolve hostname remote-sys: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

To be cuirious, I refered to it's manual

```
$ man ssh
AUTHORS
     OpenSSH is a derivative of the original and free ssh 1.2.12 release by Tatu Ylonen.
     Aaron Campbell, Bob Beck, Markus Friedl, Niels Provos, Theo de Raadt and Dug Song
     removed many bugs, re-added newer features and created OpenSSH.  Markus Friedl con-
     tributed the support for SSH protocol versions 1.5 and 2.0.

BSD                             March 30, 2018                             BSD
```

It's the latest version of today (March 30, 2018).

It seems to be updated automatically,
Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

By default nothing is updated automatically. Even if you enable automatic updates, you can check when they are installed via App Store's Updates tab. If there's nothing for today, no updates are installed today — simple.

This assumes you haven't installed or set up something non-default administrative update tool. It's perfectly possible to install non-default SSH client and then have a script to check updates for it daily and install them if available. This probably isn't the case here.

And as one can install such a script it is also possible to do so unknowingly (by something malicious)—but, again, this probably isn't the case in hand.

---

In this case, we're putting too much trust on the header section of the man page.

The ssh man page, located in `/usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1`, is missing a [`.TH`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html) line, where the date you referred to should be defined, so presumably it's just printing a fallback: "BSD" and current date.

Date can also be defined with `.Dd` line, which in ssh.1 is `.Dd $Mdocdate: September 21 2017 $`, which might be incorrectly interpreted on macOS.

If you wish to know when the SSH version you are using was released (note: released, not installed), you can check the current version with command `ssh -V` and cross reference that info with [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) to check the release date.

Comment: Maybe not, `man ls` output  `BSD  May 19, 2002`

Comment: $ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
OpenSSH 7.6/7.6p1 (2017-10-03)